# How can I use method from an class instantiated in another form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, reference

I have an class instaciaded in the `Form1` and I want call it `Form2` it is possible?

For example:

```
public TheClass thClass; //member from Form1

/* ... */ 

public void foo() { 
       thClass = new TheClass(...);
}
```

Form 2:

```
public void baa() { 
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.thClass.MethodName( .. ) ;
}
```

I'm getting the following erro when call the  `.baa()` method in `Form2`:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What's the best way to do this? `ref` ?
I'm wanting do this not instantiated  the thClass again.

I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it might be to pass the instance of TheClass in Form1 to Form2's constructor.

```
// Code from Form 1
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private TheClass thClass;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void foo()
    { 
        thClass = new TheClass(...);
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 objForm2 = new Form2(thClass);
        objForm2.Show();
    }
}

// Code From Form 2
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private TheClass thClass;
    public Form2(TheClass thCls)
    {
        thClass = thCls;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void baa(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        thClass.MethodName( .. );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this exception because `thClass` is `null` - in your example you have to call `foo()` before using `thClass`.

Reference type fields are nothing special - they can be accessed like any other public field of a class (and `Form1` is a class). In general you will want to use a property instead though and avoid public fields since any change to them will break existing consumers - a property that can only be set by the owning class you could express as

```
public TheClass SomeClass {get; private set;}
```

Comment: I get same error.. the `.foo()` method is called in `Form1`  this is not sufficient to can I call `.baa()` in `Form2`?

Comment: you got it backwards in your example - you have to first call `foo()` then you can call `form1.thClass.MethodName()`

Answer (score 0):

you should call Foo() to initizalize "thClass"....

```
public void baa() { 
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    form1.foo();
    form1.thClass.MethodName( .. ) ;
}
```

Comment: `.foo()` is called in `Form1`

Comment: I can't see where is called... is declared... but not called

Answer (score 0):

since you initialize the thClass in the foo method, you just invoke the method before you use thClass

```
public void baa() { 
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.foo();
        form1.thClass.MethodName( .. ) ;
}
```

or you can initialize directly

```
public void baa() { 
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.thClass = new TheClass(...);
        form1.thClass.MethodName( .. ) ;
}
```